# more intuitive 4 Color Map Theorem

Tags: logic

I understand the 4CT has been proven by computer but im working on an intuitive understanding.. What do you think of this:

If the most countries that can all be touching each other in 2 dimensions is 4, and we have a map that requies AT LEAST 4 colors (no silly single country maps or anything, a complex map.)

EDIT: Step 1 was unclear. Should be - Pick any remaining country. Pick another non-touching country. Continue until there are no more non-touching countries. Remove them and call them group A. All remaining countries must have been in contact with group A.

1. Pick any country. Remove all other NON-TOUCHING countries (your choice). Call them group A. All remaining countries must have been in contact with group A.
2. Repeat but this time call them group B. All remaining countries must have been in contact with group A and group B.
3. Repeat but this time call them group C. All remaining countries must have been in contact with group A and group B and group C.
4. Repeat but this time call them group D. Assign unique colors to group A B C and D.
5. If there are any countries remaining they will have been in contact with group A B C and D. i.e. 5 countries all simultaneously touching. This is not possible in 2 dimensions. No countries are remaining.

Comment: You seem to be conflating countries and groups of countries.  It isn't true that every country in group B touches every country in group A, for instance.  Statement $5$ is simply false.

Comment: If there is a country in group B that was not touching one in group A... then why wasn't it removed in the first round? (with group A).  thanks for the replies I appreciate it.

Comment: The whole idea is flawed.  Take two countries that touch a country in group A.  You put them both in group B.  Why shouldn't they touch each other?

Comment: I made an edit, I should have spelled out that you start by picking one country. Doesn't matter which one. Then pick all other remaining countries that are non-touching. So you have choices but doesn't really matter. Sorry, does it make sense now?

Comment: No it doesn't.  The same objection applies.  Do you really think that you will be able to solve a problem that eluded some of the most distinguished mathematicians in the world for over a century, in two  paragraphs containing no math at all?

Comment: yes yes how dare I... just looking for help understanding it... anyway it is NOT possible for two countries in group B to be touching, one will be left over and will go in group C. I'm not sure you see what I am saying here...?

Comment: What do you mean by "all other non touching countries"?  All countries that don't touch the first one?  They certainly can touch one another.  All countries that don't touch one another?  This is ill-defined.  There are many sets of countries that don't touch one another and different countries are in these sets.  Try your ideas out on [this game](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/map.html) and you'll probably see what's wrong.

Comment: Ok I see I didn't word it right. Yes you're right. So what I am doing is picking one of those possible sets of non-touching countries at each step. I will play with it some more. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If there are any countries remaining they will have been in contact with group A B C and D. i.e. 5 countries all simultaneously touching. This is not possible in 2 dimensions."

Why? This is what makes the 4CT hard.

Comment: So this part has not been proven?

Comment: I see! My step 5 is not right.